# How to configure openldap with ldapmodify

Tags: ldap

At the beginning i would like to apologize for my english.

I have to admit that i am totally beginner with ldap but i really would like to learn how to configure it. I've just installed package of openldap 2.4 and i faced problem during configuration. There are a lot of tutorial in internet that show how to configure ldap but practically all of them uses text editor like vim to set up server's files. When i wanted edit proper file in this method i saw this: do not edit!!! use ldapmodify. A lot of users ignore it and faced problem with crc so i did't even tried it.

My question is: How to use `ldapmodify` command to configure ldap server?

I got to know how its syntax looks and followed one tutorial but this doesnt work. I tried set olcRootDN then I typed exactly this command what i found there:

```
ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// <<EOF
```

but nothing happened. just this sign appeared:

```
>
```

How to edit olc directives using ldapmodify?
I hope you can help me

Im using CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 0):

The key concept is thet OpenLDAP configuration files are themserlves in the same format as the LDAP data.

To edit them you need to format the updates in LDIF format and apply them with `ldapmodify` or `ldapadd`.

You need first to get acquainted with LDIF format. This is paramount.

Then reading man pages for `ldapmodify` will help you, as well as reading the documentation pages on [OpenLDAP site](http://www.openldap.org).

I am not going to give you a link to any LDIF tutorial because there are so many: I think you can choose the best for you!